# Outlook VSTO Add-in Get BCC Recipient

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

If I have an Outlook MailItem and I call an Outlook VSTO add-in on it as a user that was bcc-ed onto that email, is there a way to retrieve that users email address?

It doesn’t show up in the MailItem’s recipients fields because it’s “bcc” so not sure if there’s a way to access it. It would just be the user who invoked the add-in though, so maybe there’s a property somewhere for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see BCC recipients on incoming messages by definition. The best you can do is take educated guess - look at the To and CC recipients and check if any of the recipients match any configured account in Outlook (`Application.Session.Accounts`).

Comment: Hmm what about if I create a “reply” email, is there a way to see what email that reply will be sent from? ie if I received the email to “test@email.com” and create a reply mailitem, the email gets sent from test@email.com. So would like to access that field

Comment: You can simply access `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to check which account was used.